# Save doc with PHPOffice/PHPWord

Tags: php, symfony

I need save document in docx format. For that, i use PHPOffice/PHPWord

I add it in my composer

```
"phpoffice/phpword": "dev-master"
```

Than update composer.
Than i use like example in instruction from 'Get start' section https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord.

I didn't register it in AppKernel, because if i add `new PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord()` i have error `Method getname is not defined.`.

My question is how customize it for work and where document save?

Comment: did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select PHPOffice from your root namespace. So add a Slash before your namespace. Something like this:

`new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord()`